# How to vertically order the elements inside a flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following code:

```html
<section class="body1">
    <h1 class="text1">Tours around the world</h1>
    <h3 class="text1">Great experiences</h3>
    <form action="/respuestaUsuario/">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Where are you going?">
    </form>
</section>
```

and its corresponding CSS

```css
.body1 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-image: url("../images/poolpic2.png");
}
```

I want the three elements (the h1, the h3 and the form) to be one after the other VERTICALLY.  However they appear one after the other, HORIZONTALLY.

I want them in the center of the container, and the line

```css
align-items: center;
```

actually helped them be in the center, but they are , again, not one after the other vertically as I would like them. Basically the elements look like this:

```
    h1------------h3-------------form
```

but I want them

```
-------------h1-------------
-------------h3-------------
------------form------------
```

Comment: Try this align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `flex-direction`, `justify-content`, and `align-items` properties. Specifically `flex-direction: column;`, `justify-content: center;`, and `align-items: center;`

`flex-direction: column;` specifies that you want the items (children) to have a vertical orientation.

`justify-content: center;` horizontally centers the items on the main axis.

`align-items: center;` vertically centers the items on the cross axis.

```css
.body1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  /* para que se ajuste el tamano de la imagen al contenedor */
  background-image: url("../images/poolpic2.png");
}
```

```html
<section class="body1">

  <!-- <img src="./assets/images/poolpic2.png" alt="pool-pic"> -->
  <h1 class="text1">Tours around the world</h1>
  <h3 class="text1">Great experiences</h3>
  <form action="/respuestaUsuario/">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Where are you going?">
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks. It looks like I want now, except that it is not centered vertically speaking. That is, the three elements are at the top of the container, centered horizontally speaking, but not vertically (I don't want them at the top, I want them in the middle)

Comment: Well you can also use `justify-content: center;` to vertically center them in the container. But your headings have margins so that might also be why you're having issues.

Comment: @chris56tv give `html`, `body`, and `div.body1` a height of 100%

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if you have set the display mode as "flex"（display:flex, the default of "flex-direction" is "row" even if you haven't typed it in your CSS. So you can add "flex-direction:column" to change the default and the elements could be one after one vertically.

Comment: I think you mean "row".

Comment: Sorry,I've made a mistake:the "raw" should be "row".And show the appreciation to @EternalHour for correcting my answer

Answer (score 0):

First give `div.body1` `display: flex`, with `flex-flow: column`, and `align-items: center` to center horizontally. Next give `html, body, and div.body1` a `height: 100%`, and finally give `div.body1` an `align-items:center` to center vertically:

```css
html, body, .body1{
   height: 100%;
}

.body1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  /* para que se ajuste el tamano de la imagen al contenedor */
  background-image: url("../images/poolpic2.png");
}

h1{
   margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="body1">
  <h1 class="text1">Tours around the world</h1>
  <h3 class="text1">Great experiences</h3>
  <form action="/respuestaUsuario/">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Where are you going?">
  </form>
</section>
```